# How to automatically switch between DHCP Server and Client mode on startup of several devices?

Tags: linux, embedded, dhcp, busybox

I do wan't to have several embedded devices to boot up at the same time and automatically select the first booted device as the dhcp server and the others as client. But every client can be the server on another start. So they are all running the same custom busybox based linux system.

I have full control of the system. 
I would start the dhcp client on all devices first and the check if a server is present.

Is there any implementation for this case in the wild?

Best regards, 
Pascal